# jQuery: wrong values when reading CSS properties after removing transforms

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I'm working on a project that uses CSS3 transitions and animations and some time I need to be sure to measure non-transformed values of CSS properties even if there are transformations applied.

To do this I:

1. temporarily backup and remove transformations
2. read properties I need
3. restore previous transformations

Doing this I've found a strange behavior: I get correct values **only** proceed step by step with the debugger.

I know of browser properties batching on read/write and for that reason I've put `offsetTop` property reading after setting/restoring transforms, but with no luck.

**Note:** this behavior seem to be cross-browser consistant.

**This is a minimal setup to test**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery.fn.extend({
    setupIdentity: function() {
      var restore_props = [],
        i;
      for (i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) {
        restore_props.push({
          "animation-play-state": this[i].style.animationPlayState,
          transform: this[i].style.transform,
          display: this[i].style.display
        });
      }

      var identity_props = {
        "animation-play-state": "paused",
        transform: "none",
        display: ""
      };
      this.css(identity_props);

      for (i = 0; i < this.length; ++i)
        var top = this[i].offsetTop;

      return restore_props;
    },

    restoreIdentity: function(restore_props) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) {
        this.eq(i).css(restore_props[i]);
        var top = this[i].offsetTop;
      }

      return this;
    }
  });

  $("#toggle").on("click", function() {
    var wrap = $("#win_wrap"),
      win = $("#win");
    if (wrap.hasClass("iconized")) {
      var restore = wrap.setupIdentity();
      var restore2 = win.setupIdentity();

      var win_width = win.width(),
        win_height = win.height();
      var win_offset = win.offset();
      console.log(win_width, win_height);
      console.log(win_offset);

      win.css(win_offset);

      win.restoreIdentity(restore2);
      wrap.restoreIdentity(restore);
    }

    wrap.toggleClass("iconized");
  });

  console.log($("#win").width(), $("#win").height());
  console.log($("#win").offset());
});
```

```css
.window {
  background: #DDD;
  background-size: contain;
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  outline: none;
  z-index: 100;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
.wwindow.trs-iconizable {
  transition-property: opacity, transform;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transform-origin: top right;
  opacity: 1.0;
  transform: scale(1.0);
}
.wwindow.trs-iconizable.iconized {
  opacity: 0.0;
  transform: scale(0.0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <button id="toggle">Show/Hide</button>
  <div id="apps_wrapper">
    <div id="win_wrap" class="wwindow trs-iconizable" style="">
      <div id="win" class="window" style="position: fixed; left: 40px; top: 40px; min-width: 15em; min-height: 5em; width: auto; height: auto;">text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/oscpkt36/) is the test case fiddle.
To verify if you have solved my issue you must:

1. open the devtools console.
2. click on `show/hide` button (the transition scale down the window)
3. click another time on `show/hide` and check on console.

If you read **same values** on all clicks (even if in between transition), and you see the window repositioned on same place every time, you have fixed my property reading problem.

Comment: I see width and height being pulled are those the ones that keep turning up as incorrect?

Comment: @Culyx No, the wrong reading is on `win.offset()`, but i've readed that jQuery have some bugs measuring CSS-transformed elements.

Comment: Fair enough, the reason I asked is that elements with a size of auto for width/height will give weird results in certain conditions as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference.

I've readed on jQuery bugtracker that the library have some bugs measuring CSS-transformed elements ([here](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8362), [here](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11114), etc).

To have consistent results I opted for using `window.getComputedStyle()` that is widely supported as you can see on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=getcomputedstyle). This way i can also avoid clear and restore of CSS transforms.